# python: if (substring X in string Y) only true for last characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code only returns true when the substring is at the end. How do I fix it to consider any substring? Data looks like this:

prediction:

1. dog
2. cat

actual:

1. red,dog
2. cat,blue

returns true then returns false

```
with open("test_class.txt") as g:
    prediction = g.readlines()

with open("y_smallTest.txt") as g:
    actual = g.readlines()

for n in range(len(prediction)):
    if prediction[n] in actual[n]:
        correct += 1
    else:
        incorrect +=1
```

Edit: .rstrips works! The expected output is true, true

Comment: Without seeing those files, we can't really help. `in` works anywhere in the string, not just at the end.

Comment: You want to check this for items in same line? and what is the expected output? Also your code is checking the member ship with `in` and it means you are checking in all over the string, not just end, and note that you have new lines at the trailing of your items, (because of `fileobj.readlines()`)

Comment: `readlines` includes the line terminators in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines` gives you each line include the newline at the end of the line. So you're doing comparisons like `"cat\n" in "cat,blue\n"`. Since there isn't a newline in the right place, the check fails.

Try this to strip the newlines off the end of each line:

```
with open("test_class.txt") as g:
    prediction = [line.rstrip() for line in g]

with open("y_smallTest.txt") as g:
    actual = [line.rstrip() for line in g]

for n in range(len(prediction)):
    if prediction[n] in actual[n]:
        correct += 1
    else:
        incorrect +=1
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps a better rewrite is to use zip and just iterate through the files:

```
with open("test_class.txt") as predictions, open("y_smallTest.txt") as actuals:
    for prediction, actual in zip(predictions, actual):
        if prediction.rstrip() in actual:
            correct += 1
        else:
            incorrect += 1
```

Comment: I don't why this is down voted, I feel this is right approach, hence upvoting this

Answer (score 0):

`'cat' in 'cat,blue'` returns True

Please make small change to your script

```
if prediction[n].strip() in actual[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in the list returned by `readlines` will include the `\n` at the end of each line, so you are *actually* testing `'dog\n' in 'red,dog\n'`, which is fine, and `'cat\n' in 'cat,blue\n'`, which is not.

To fix it, you can use `strip()` to remove the line terminators (and any other enclosing whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to *rstrip* the *newline* from each line of the first file so you don't compare `dog\n` with `red,dog\n`, the newline on the string you are testing is irrelevant.  You can also use *zip* and read the files line by line withput the need for *readlines* and indexing:

```
with open("test_class.txt") as f1, open("y_smallTest.txt") as f2:
    correct = incorrect = 0
    for a, b in zip(f1, f2):
        if a.rstrip() in b:
              correct += 1
        else:
             incorrect += 1
```

If you want exact matches then you will need to *rstrip* and *split* on the comma:

```
with open("test_class.txt") as f1, open("y_smallTest.txt") as f2:
    correct = incorrect = 0
    for a, b in zip(f1, f2):
        if a.rstrip() in b.rstrip().split(","):
            correct += 1
        else:
            incorrect += 1
```

The difference on splitting would mean *dog* would not match *dogs,cats*.